# Highlight/mouseover broken with Polygons in KMZ file Google Maps v3

Tags: coding-style, google-maps-api-3, hover, polygon, kml

I'm trying to get the highlight/hover/mouseover styles working for a KMZ Placemark using Google Maps v3. When I open the KMZ file with Google Earth, the appropriate area when hovered will change to the highlightPlacemark style as intended. But when I load this KMZ onto a Google Map object, the style never changes.

Here is what the styles look like:

```
<Style id="highlightPlacemark">
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>a60000ff</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<StyleMap id="exampleStyleMap">
    <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#normalPlacemark</styleUrl>
    </Pair>
    <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#highlightPlacemark</styleUrl>
    </Pair>
</StyleMap>
<Style id="normalPlacemark">
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>a6ffffff</color>
    </PolyStyle>
</Style>
```

Here is what the Placemark looks like:

```
<Placemark id="1">
    <name>Test</name>
    <Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet>
    <styleUrl>#exampleStyleMap</styleUrl>
    <Polygon>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                    ...lots of coordinates here...
                </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

Does this feature only work in Google Earth or is there a workaround to make it work in Google Maps v3?
The only way I can think of is to create individual Polygon objects, and providing the coordinates to them individually. This allows you to use the mouseover event of the Polygon class. I would rather have all my Polygons in 1 single file though...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been reported on the Google Maps API Issues tracker as #131 seen [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=131).
The issue was closed without a comment/reason other than "WontFix".

KmlLayers are rendered as tiles, so I guess this makes it harder to use mouseover events.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very old question but thought it might help someone. Not all KML tags are supported in Google Maps. (Most if not all are supported in Google Earth.) For example:

```
<StyleMap></StyleMap>
```

is *not* supported in Google Maps but works in Earth. So this is why it doesn't work.

I'm currently looking for a solution to hover state for KML polygons in Google Maps as well. (Without additional javascript or messy duplicate workarounds.) But it's not top priority, so if I can't find I a solution soon I'll just do without that feature for now.